# How make from 4 variables only two in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot, lateral-join

I have the following table
[image]

and want to achieve the following result

[image]

As a result, group1 and group 2 are grouped to GROUP, and quantity1/2 to QUANTITY. I tried with cross apply, but the table starts being too big and with duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server, I would recommend `cross apply` to unpivot:

```
select t.date, t.fund, x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (values (t.group1, t.quantity1), (t.group2, t.quantity2)) as x(grp, qty)
```

Lateral joins are a powerful tool. This is more efficient than `union all`, because the table is scanned only once.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply an `UNION` operation, as follow:

```
SELECT date, fund, group1 as grp, quantity1 as quantity
FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT date, fund, group2, quantity2
FROM yourtable
```

I've used `UNION ALL` because you have group1 and group2 always different (as your data sample), so you don't apply with `ALL`, the distinct operation.

Comment: don't you need to alias group2 and quantity2 too?

Comment: @T.Peter: No dear, the alias is OK on the first query. Other goes in positional way

Comment: tbh I never know this, so the rest of the column will auto union follow by position? thx for the info.